# How to print N number of primes in Visual basic (forms)?

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have this visual basic code to receive user input and print out that many primes. For instance if a user inputs 5, the output should be: 1, 3, 5, 7, 11. But I found difficulty with it.Here is my code:

```
Dim i, n, input, currentPrime As Integer
        Dim Wrap As String = Chr(10) & Chr(13)
        input = txtInput.Text
        currentPrime = 1
        txtAns.Text = "Prime Numbers are : " & Wrap
        Do While (currentPrime <= input)
            For i = currentPrime To input
                For j = 2 To Fix(i / 2) + 1
                    If i Mod j = 0 Then
                        n = 1
                    End If
                Next
                If n = 1 Then
                    n = 0
                Else
                    txtAns.Text = txtAns.Text & Wrap & i & " is a prime number " & Wrap
                End If
            Next
            currentPrime += 1
        Loop
```

Comment: i have a problem regarding my codes. I found difficulty with it. My output should be if a user inputs 5, the output should be: 1, 3, 5, 7, 11. But mine is till 499 :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print N number of primes in Vb.net (forms)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27446434/how-to-print-n-number-of-primes-in-vb-net-forms)

Comment: how can i start my sequence by 2?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
    Dim i, n, input As Integer
    Dim Wrap As String = Chr(10) & Chr(13)
    input = txtInput.Text
    Dim found = 0
    Dim output = "Prime Numbers are : " & Wrap
    While found < input
        i = i + 1
        For j = 2 To Fix(i / 2) + 1
            If i Mod j = 0 Then
                n = 1
            End If
        Next
        If n = 1 Then
            n = 0
        Else
            output = output & Wrap & i & " is a prime number " & Wrap
            found = found + 1
        End If
    End While
    txtAns.Text = output
```

Comment: oh it works sr! Thank you so much :) This is my main problem By listing the first six prime numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, and 13, we can see that the 6th prime is 13.

What is the 10 001st prime number?

Comment: where can i insert my validation? Dim letters As Boolean

        If txtAns.Text = "" Or letters = IsNumeric(txtAns.Text) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please input a number!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
            txtAns.Clear()

Comment: Your validation should be placed at the top of the routine, with an Exit Sub if the validation failed. Please mark this as the answer if it is correct.

Comment: its not working. and yet I forgot, 2 must be in the 1st sequence. coz 1 is not a prime number. TIA!